# if the required message is a standard message type available with ROS, do we still need to define it in msg/xxxx.msg?

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If my message type is geometry_msgs/WrenchStamped, do I still need to define it in msg folder or I can skip it? As I am not using a custom message type.

Thanks
Anirudh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364458/if-the-required-message-is-a-standard-message-type-available-with-ros,-do-we-still-need-to-define-it-in-msg/xxxx.msg?/) by [Anirudh_Vajpeyi](https://answers.ros.org/users/52250/anirudh_vajpeyi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can skip it. All standard message types are already run through gencpp/genpy/gennodejs/etc. during build time of the ROS distribution packages to generate the c++, python, and node.js message definition classes. You can verify this using `locate` on your machine:

```
> locate WrenchStamped
/opt/ros/melodic/include/geometry_msgs/WrenchStamped.h
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geometry_msgs/msg/_WrenchStamped.py
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geometry_msgs/msg/_WrenchStamped.pyc
/opt/ros/melodic/share/common-lisp/ros/geometry_msgs/msg/WrenchStamped.lisp
/opt/ros/melodic/share/common-lisp/ros/geometry_msgs/msg/_package_WrenchStamped.lisp
/opt/ros/melodic/share/gennodejs/ros/geometry_msgs/msg/WrenchStamped.js
/opt/ros/melodic/share/geometry_msgs/msg/WrenchStamped.msg
/opt/ros/melodic/share/roseus/ros/geometry_msgs/msg/WrenchStamped.l
/opt/ros/melodic/share/rviz/icons/classes/WrenchStamped.png
```

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2020-10-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A standard message type does not need to be defined in the msg folder. Only [custom message](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages)s need to be defined there.

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-10-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1